# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestPlan.getConfigurationParameters() when trying to run JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit

When I try to run any JUnit tests on my project on Eclipse, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestPlan.getConfigurationParameters()Lorg/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters;
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.UniqueIdTrackingListener.testPlanExecutionStarted(UniqueIdTrackingListener.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.lambda$testPlanExecutionStarted$4(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:82)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.notifyTestExecutionListeners(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.access$100(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:27)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.testPlanExecutionStarted(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:82)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:149)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: either you are calling a method with the wrong parameters, or you have a conflict in dependencies, one of them has that method,t he other doesn't

Comment: Probably the project is using a version of JUnit that's incompatible with the version Eclipse uses. Show us the project dependencies (pom if it's a Maven project, for example) and what version of Eclipse you're using.

Comment: @E-Riz, I'm using Eclipse version: 2022-09 (4.25.0). I will update my question to list the project dependencies related to JUnit.

Comment: @Stultuske, I think I have a conflict but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Check all the instances of that class you have in your dependency tree. Check which one you need, and exclude the others from your build

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [Stultuske's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75696910/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-junit-platform-launcher-testplan-getconfigurati#comment133540809_75696910), this is usually an indicator for a dependency conflict.

JUnit provides a [BOM](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata-junit-bom):

> The *Bill of Materials* POM provided under the following Maven coordinates can be used to ease dependency management when referencing multiple of the above artifacts using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) or [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import).

If you are using e.g. Maven, add this to your dependency management:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried adding this but it didn't work.