# Problem when running unit test with Junit5

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to do some units tests but no matter what, I always received the following error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ScriptEvaluationException`

This is from the POM:

[image: Pom's]

I think that my IDE is not recognizing the library itself.

This is the outcome when I put this `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=:jupiter-api`
[image: dependecy tree]

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 and JDK 17.0.2.

Comment: JUnit Jupiter offers a BOM, which usually helps when it comes to `NoClassDefFoundError`s and the like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75700503/3429133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed from my POM the `<version>` of each dependency of the `<groupId>` that has Jupiter and updated BOM's in the `<properties>` tag.

Comment: So it is fixed now?

Comment: Yes. After I made these changes, the tests worked just fine.